# Composer update shows mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

Tags: php, linux, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to update my compose but i get the following error message can anyone tell me what this is.

```
root@linuxmachine:/var/www/html/# composer update
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 815800320) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 815800320) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223
```

Comment: Since the errors say "Cannot allocate memory" and "Out of memory", my guess would be that it runs out of memory.

Comment: Here is the output of 

`free -m
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            985         136         660          37         188         675
Swap:             0           0           0`

How can i allocate more memory and fix this problem

Comment: How much total memory do you have for the machine?

Comment: `df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            480M     0  480M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M  632K   98M   1% /run
/dev/vda1       9.6G  3.9G  5.7G  41% /
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1001`

Comment: If you only have 1G for the machine, it won't be enough to run Composer. You need at least 1.5G RAM to run it.

Comment: can we tweak this? Yes right now i am running this on 1G RAM

Comment: You might be able to use some disk space as swap (lots of google links out there, couldn't tell you now and that's a SuperUser question anyway), but I don't think you have enough disk space to recommend that, either.

Comment: currently i have 5.7G free disk space can we use this as a swap

Comment: You can run the composer command on another machine and then upload the result. If you go the route of using swap for this you'd best buckle up and get ready to wait a loooong time for it to complete.

Comment: @Sammitch i did not get you run the composer command on another machine and then upload the result???

Comment: Thanks a lot i will check if that solve my issue @rob006

Comment: Also, do not use `composer update` on your production server. Use it on your development environment and then use `composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev` on your production

Answer (score 0):

Usually that is a problem with the "memory_limit" directive in your php.ini. Try increasing the value assigned to memory_limit.